# express checkout keep loading and didn't return to merchant

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am using paypal sandbox to doing testing, however after click the continue button that i wish to complete the transaction, but the page is keep loading. So i click to go back on the browser, and then click to go forward again, then it will only display "You've already completed your purchase. Please click Close to continue to the merchant." My problem is i want it auto return me the success page, but not click the back and forward to view the return to merchant. thanks you very much and appreciate your answer.

Comment: I'm also getting this problem. Has anyone resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes this is pretty common if you log in and out of accounts alot.

Clear your cache/cookies and try again; should do the trick.

Rest assured that it is very unlikely your customers will run into this issue, because this is caused by logging into and out of buyer and seller accounts over and over. The cookies get confused and then this happens (among some other things).